# Spreecommerce : Checkout doesn't work without product variants

Tags: ruby-on-rails, spree, variants

If I don't have/want to setup product variants, I don't get the option to "add to card" and I can't checkout either.

Am I obliged to have more than one product variants in order to proceed?

Comment: Every product has a `master` variant. This the most basic product available and may or may not have any `variant_options` assigned to it. So to answer your question, it is perfectly possible to declare a product without any `variant_options`. When the `buy` button gets clicked with no options selected it will just assign the master variant inside the cart.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

From the official documentation:

[Every single product has a master variant, which tracks basic information such as a count on hand, a price and a SKU. Whenever a product is created, a master variant for that product will be created too.](https://guides.spreecommerce.com/developer/products.html#master-variants)